# SVN call doesn't work when script is called using PHP

Tags: php, powershell, svn

I have an issue where an SVN call within a PowerShell script behaves differently if the script is called using the command line vs PHP.

My PHP page creates an HTML page that lists the differences between two different SVN tags. When running the script directly in PowerShell the script/svn call preforms as expected. When calling the script using PHP, SVN errors noting that it is unable to connect to the repository.

Using the sample code at the bottom of this post I get the following results:

- Running the script in both PowerShell and Command Prompt windows yields an execution status of True (in the `$?` variable) and I get the project list in the TXT file.
- Running the script using the PHP page I get an execuation status of False and no project list in the TXT file. Additionally, I get the following on the PHP page, noteably the `Unable to connect to a repository` error from stderr.

```
COMMAND: powershell.exe -InputFormat none -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -NoProfile R:\scripts\test.ps1
STATUS: False
ERROR: svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL '<urlPath>'
```

---

**test.ps1**

```
$OUTFILE = "R:\scripts\test.txt"
$SVNUSER="<username>"
$SVNPW="<password>"
$BRANCH_URL = "<pathToProject>"

$BRANCHES=svn ls --username $SVNUSER --password $SVNPW $BRANCH_URL
$status = $?
Out-File $OUTFILE -encoding "ASCII" -inputObject "$status"
Out-File $OUTFILE -encoding "ASCII" -Append -inputObject "$BRANCHES"

out-host -inputObject $status
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$buildCmd = "R:\\scripts\\test.ps1";
$cmd = "powershell.exe -InputFormat none -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -NoProfile $buildCmd";
echo "COMMAND: $cmd";
echo "<br/>";

$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout
    2 => array("pipe", "w")   // stderr 
  );
  set_time_limit(1800);
  ob_implicit_flush(true);
  $process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
  if (is_resource($process))
  {
    while( ! feof($pipes[1]))
    {
      $returnMessage = fgets($pipes[1], 1024);
      if (strlen($returnMessage) == 0) break;
        print "STATUS: $returnMessage<br>";
        ob_flush();
        flush();

      $errorMessage = fgets($pipes[2], 1024);
      if (strlen($errorMessage) == 0) break;
        print "ERROR: $errorMessage";
    }
  }
?>
```

---

I'm trying to figure out why the SVN command in the script is not able to see the repository when called from the PHP page, but can in any other scope.

Comment: When you say "command line" do you mean `powershell.exe -InputFormat none ...` or `php test.php`?

Comment: Most likely this is a permission issue in the end. Keep in mind that _typically_ when executing a php script is triggered via a http server which means that the process is executed under a different user account than an interactive user account on the system. MS windows is not a multi user environment like Linux, but still there are differences between different accounts. And it does make sense to reduce the permissions of such a process for security reasons. So find out what account that is and how that accounts environment differs from that of your usual user account.

Comment: @arkascha - I've run into permissions issues before but the script is executing, it is just the svn line within the script that is preforming differently. Since I'm explicitly passing username and password to the svn command it seems there shouldn't be a permissions issue.